# Let $w>0$.compute the matrix $e^{A}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Let $w>0$.compute the matrix $e^{A}$,where $$A=\begin{bmatrix}  0 & w \\ -w& 0  
 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Simplest approach is to find a quadratic equation for the matrix $A$, and then use this to simplify the Taylor series definition of $e^A$.

Comment: Hint: $A=wX$ with $$X=\pmatrix{0&1\cr-1&0\cr}.$$ Computing the powers $X,X^2,X^3,X^4$ first will help you see the light.

Comment: thanks...by using your logic i solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let $A=wX$, where $X=\pmatrix{0&1\cr-1&0\cr}$ and $w>0$.Now on expanding we will get $e^{A}$=$I(\cos w)+X(\sin w)$ which will ultimately give $$e^{A}=\begin{bmatrix}  \cos w & \sin w \\ -\sin w& \cos w   \\ \end{bmatrix}$$